# How do i obtain a more rounded edge

Tags: modeling, geometry

[image][image]I'm trying to trace and image with vertices but the rounded parts come out misshapen or oblong-ish. I've also done this shape in a more freeform fashion giving me excellent results, but there's more to the model that i feel like is going to force me into a tracing method anyway because I'm super new 3D modeling. I think the shape comes out misshapen because it's not a perfect top-down view. So are there any tricks to get it more rounded, should i be using a bezier curve to do this?. Anyhow here are the images. The first image is the image i'm modeling from, the second image is the one i did freeform  and the last image is the one i traced with vertices.[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell what is your problem as you don't show any wireframe. If I had to do this kind of object I would begin with the inner circles, then the main outer circle, then extend the shape, then extrude, bevel, add edge loops to sharp the edges, etc...

[image]

Comment: Thanks i'm going to give it a go tomorrow evening.